# Moving div right and left on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to make div go left the first time i click on it, back to its original position the second time, left again the third etc..

So why isn't this working:
http://jsfiddle.net/kS7KE/2/

```
    var checker = new Boolean();
checker = true;
if (checker = true){
    $("#div").click(function () {   
        $(this).animate({left: "10%"},400);   
        checker = false;
    });
}
if (checker != true){
    $("#div").click(function () {   
        $(this).animate({left: "30%"},400);   
        checker = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so much code ? :)

```
var checker = true;
$("#div").click(function () {
    targetLeft = checker ? "10%" : "30%";
    $(this).animate({left: targetLeft},400);   
    checker ? checker = false : checker = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kS7KE/5/

Comment: We need to go shorter: `$(this).animate({left: checker ? "10%" : "30%"},400);checker = !checker;` ;D

Comment: @Andy get rid of all those spaces! ;)

Comment: @lbstr done. `$(this).animate({left:c?'10%':'30%'},400);c=!c;` (note: don't do this :) )

Answer (score 3):

A few issues:

1. `if (checker = true)`

   You are using an assignment (`=`) rather than a check for equality (`==` or `===`).
2. Your check happens at bind time

   You want to check `checker` in your click event.

Soemthing like this will do the trick:

```
var checker = new Boolean();
checker = true;
$("#div").click(function () { 
    var left = checker ? "10%" : "30%";
    $(this).animate({left: left},400);   
    checker = !checker;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/L4TN3/

Comment: I think you need to change the checker assignment to checker = !checker

Answer (score 3):

First, don't use `new Boolean()`.  Just initialize it like `var checker = true;`

Second, you're using an assignment operator in your first conditional (`checker = true`).

Third, you're not executing the conditional on each click.

Fourth, your code is pretty convoluted. Here's a sample:

```
var checker = true;
$('#div').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: checker ? "10%" : "30%"
    });
    checker = !checker;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not attach multiple event handlers to the same object which conflict with each other like you did. Here is a bit clearer and simpler version which does the same thing your code is supposed to do. As you can see it makes use of only one event handler.

```
var checker = true;
$('#div').click(function(){
    if(checker){
       $(this).animate({left: "10%"},400);   
       checker = false; 
    } else {
        $(this).animate({left: "30%"},400);   
        checker = true;
    }
});
```

Additionally you perform an assignment in your first if statement (single `=`) instead of using `==` to compare your operands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the click event once, and do the logic in it : http://jsfiddle.net/kS7KE/2/

```
var checker = new Boolean();
checker = true;
$("#div").click(function () { 

if (checker == true){       
        $(this).animate({left: "10%"},400);   
        checker = false;
    }
else{

        $(this).animate({left: "30%"},400);   
        checker = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    var checker = new Boolean();
checker = true;

    $("#div").click(function () { 
        if (checker == true){
        $(this).animate({left: "10%"},400);   
        checker = false;
            }
        else
        {
            $(this).animate({left: "30%"},400);   
        checker = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checker = true;

$("#div").on('click', function () {
    if (checker == true) {
        checker = false;
        $(this).animate({
            left: "10%"
        }, 400);

    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "30%"
        }, 400);
        checker = true;
    }
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/kS7KE/9/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var checker = true;
$("#div").on('click', function () {
    var left = checker ? '10%' : '30%';
    $(this).animate({left: left},400);   
    checker = !checker
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain to the OP why your code works and why his doesn't.